# Python Equivalent to phpinfo()

Tags: python, php

Quite simply, is there a [python](http://www.python.org/) equivalent to php's [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)? If so, what is it and how do I use it (a link to a reference page would work great).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this one out!

[pyinfo() A good looking phpinfo-like python script](https://web.archive.org/web/20171124162145/https://bran.name/articles/pyinfo-a-good-looking-phpinfo-like-python-script)

**2023 Update**: *[this script has been moved to Gist](https://gist.github.com/branneman/951825)*,
but more importantly: [one of the commenters made it compatible with Python 3](https://gist.github.com/branneman/951825?permalink_comment_id=1611004#gistcomment-1611004)

Comment: The link here is now dead. Is there a new one? - however, https://pypi.org/project/pyinfo/ and https://github.com/mastropinguino/pyinfo

Comment: However, I'm not able to get this to work in current python 3.9.2

Comment: @rfay I've just fixed the link to a web archive version, and added the code from the original gist. There's also a [pyinfo() for python 3](https://gist.github.com/branneman/951825?permalink_comment_id=1611004#gistcomment-1611004) from a commenter.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this out: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showpost.php?s=f55e18d344e3783edd98aef5be809ac8&p=4632018&postcount=4

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing directly comparable to `phpinfo()`, but you can get some bits of information ...

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.6.4 (r264:75706, Feb  6 2010, 01:49:44) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]'

>>> sys.platform
'darwin'

>>> sys.modules.keys()
['copy_reg', 'sre_compile', '_sre', 'encodings', 'site', ... ]

>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'

>>> import platform
>>> platform.architecture()
('32bit', '')

>>> platform.machine()
'i386'

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no similar function. However, the [platform module](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html) allows you to access some basic information about the machine, OS and Python.

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo prints information about running PHP version, loaded modules and so on.

AFAIK Python does not such a conventient function that dumps the complete configuration.

But you should have a look at the `sys` package.

```
import sys

# print all imported modules since start
print sys.modules

# print load path
print sys.path

...
```

Check out Python's [sys-library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).