# How to know what django version i use? is it 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2?

Tags: python, django

this is the first time i use django. I'm really a beginner. And this is the first time i see the page "It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.". it's mean i'm now have a django+python in my xampp server. So i cam to the question ?

1. How to know what django version  i use? is it 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2 ?
2. where i can read it in my django folder (a file name) and how i can use code/function to print the django version ?
3. is there any subtitute for phpinfo() in python ?

Comment: [`python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16805125/673991)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check Django version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468397/how-to-check-django-version)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As to your first question:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/unternet$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct  9 2010, 11:40:09) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.get_version()
'1.2.3'
```

Comment: hopefully that answers your 2nd question also. as to the 3rd: I don't know yet (I'm just starting with it myself) but I suspect the answer is "no", at least not on the same scale as phpinfo().

Comment: that actually is really good for older version of django then 11,as from that one is used django-admin --version, but it did not worked for another project where indeed django is 10.4(and I was getting ImportError: No module named 'django'

Answer (score 9):

```
import django
django.VERSION
```

Answer (score 2):

For the third question, you can get the list of available modules from the interpreter prompt:

```
>>> help()

help> modules
```

This will (eventually) give you a list of available modules.

For other info, you can use the `sys` module:

```
import sys

sys.version # Python version
sys.platform # platform
```

Answer (score 2):

For your third question, [Python Equivalent to phpinfo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572371/python-equivalent-to-phpinfo)

Answer (score 2):

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Output:

> Validating models...
>
> 0 errors found
> February 27, 2015 - 14:25:41
> ***Django version 1.6.5***, using settings ...
> ....