# How to check Django version

Tags: python, django, command-line, command, version

I have to use [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) and [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) for our application. So, I have two versions of Python, 2.6 and 2.7. Now I have installed Django. I could run the sample application for testing Django successfully. But how do I check whether Django uses the 2.6 or 2.7 version and what version of modules Django uses?

Comment: Shortest way - `python3 -m django --version`

Comment: In my installation python3 is not recognized. This works: python -m django --version

Comment: I believe since a somewhat old Python version is preinstalled on MacOS systems, a suffix of "3" is required on "python" command to avoid confusions from the OS side on which version to use.
This isn't required on Windows systems so @AnttiA 's solution works just fine.

Comment: another shortest way is `django-admin --version`

Comment: The suggested commands show your installed django version, not the code version. Check the *requirements.txt* `cat src/requirements.txt | grep "Django=="` or in your application's settings.py file, on the fifth line you'll see something like `Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django x.x.x` (for the user-specific question, the accepted answers are the way, but I found that this could also be useful).

Answer (score 802, accepted):

Django 1.5 supports Python 2.6.5 and later.

If you're under Linux and want to check the Python version you're using, run `python -V` from the command line.

If you want to check the Django version, open a Python console and type

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 0, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: Just dive into env before you check the version, otherwise no module named django.

Comment: This says - `AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'VERSION'`

Answer (score 425):

Basically the same as [bcoughlan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468505/3798217), but here it is as an executable command:

```
$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
2.0
```

Comment: Combining Brady Emerson and bcoughlan:  ```python -c "import django; print(django.VERSION)"``` returns 
```(1, 8, 5, 'final', 0)```

Comment: You should do `python -c "import django; print(django.__version__)"` instead. It also returns `'2.2.4'` (it's [just a call to `get_version()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/__init__.py#L5)) and is the standard followed by most other libraries because it's [defined in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names). It works since [Django 1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8/django/__init__.py#L5)

Answer (score 287):

If you have installed the application:

```
$ django-admin --version
3.2.6
```

Comment: As May 2018 (the date I've tested this answer again), it shows version as 1.11.5 despite I've installed 2.0.1. But `>> django.VERSION` in python shell displays the right version

Comment: this worked for me: ubuntu 18.04, virtualenv with P 3.6 and Django 2.2

Comment: For older versions it is `django-admin.py --version`. Depending on how you've done your python installation, you may even need `python django-admin.py --version`.

Comment: This works for me in 2022, ubuntu 20.02, virtualenv with Python 3.8 and Django 4.0.2

Comment: this just shows you the django-admin version. it's `python3 -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"` that will give you the actual django version installed

Answer (score 121):

Go to your [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) project home directory and do:

```
./manage.py --version
```

Comment: I like this one as we as Django devs often use the manage.py functionalities. You can also use 'python manage.py version' (no need for --)

Answer (score 55):

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.6.1
```

I am using the [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) (Python GUI).

Answer (score 52):

If you have [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), you can also do a

```
pip freeze
```

and it will show your all component version including Django .

You can pipe it through grep to get just the Django version. That is,

```
josh@villaroyale:~/code/djangosite$ pip freeze | grep Django
Django==1.4.3
```

Answer (score 49):

As you say you have two versions of Python, I assume they are in different [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) (e.g. venv) or perhaps [Conda environments](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).

When you installed Django, it was likely in only one environment. It is possible that you have two different versions of Django, one for each version of python.

In from a Unix/Mac terminal, you can check your Python version as follows:

```
$ python --version
```

If you want to know the source:

```
$ which python
```

And to check the version of Django:

```
$ python -m django --version
```

Answer (score 37):

For [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1093322/1551116):

```
import sys
sys.version
```

For Django (as mentioned by others here):

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

The potential problem with simply checking the version, is that versions get upgraded and so the code can go out of date. You want to make sure that '1.7' < '1.7.1' < '1.7.5' < '1.7.10'. A normal string comparison would fail in the last comparison:

```
>>> '1.7.5' < '1.7.10'
False
```

The solution is to use [StrictVersion from distutils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972866/1551116).

```
>>> from distutils.version import StrictVersion
>>> StrictVersion('1.7.5') < StrictVersion('1.7.10')
True
```

Comment: What about using `django.VERSION`, which already comes as a tuple? I'm pretty sure doing `django.VERSION >= (1, 8)` will always work as intended.

Answer (score 22):

There are various ways to get the Django version. You can use any one of the following given below according to your requirements.

**Note:** ***If you are working in a virtual environment then please load your python environment***

---

### Terminal Commands

1. `python -m django --version`
2. `django-admin --version` or `django-admin.py version`
3. `./manage.py --version` or `python manage.py --version`
4. `pip freeze | grep Django`
5. `python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"`
6. `python manage.py runserver --version`

---

### Django Shell Commands

1. `import django
   django.get_version()` OR
   `django.VERSION`
2. `from django.utils import version
   version.get_version()`  OR  `version.get_complete_version()`
3. `import pkg_resources
   pkg_resources.get_distribution('django').version`

*(Feel free to modify this answer, if you have some kind of correction or you want to add more related information.)*

Answer (score 18):

Simply type `python -m django --version`  or type `pip freeze` to see all the versions of installed modules including Django.

Comment: no reason for this to be downvoted at all, it is one of the most concise answers.

Answer (score 15):

```
django-admin --version
python manage.py --version
pip freeze | grep django
```

Comment: You'll need to use `python manage.py --version` Note the double `-`

Comment: @Shawnzam yes of course a typo.. Thanks a lot..Answer edited

Comment: I needed to make the d in Django capital for grep to find it.

Comment: The first command and the second return two different version numbers for me.

Answer (score 13):

For checking using a Python shell, do the following.

```
>>>from django import get_version
>>> get_version()
```

If you wish to do it in Unix/Linux shell with a single line, then do

```
python -c 'import django; print(django.get_version())'
```

Once you have developed an application, then you can check version directly using the following.

```
python manage.py runserver --version
```

Answer (score 11):

Type in your CMD or terminal:

```
python -m django --version
```

Answer (score 11):

**Official Documentation**

**First:**

```
python -m django --version
```

**Second:**

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

Answer (score 8):

**Django version or any other package version**

Open the terminal or command prompt

Type

```
pip show django
```

or

```
pip3 show django
```

You can find any package version...

Example:

```
pip show tensorflow

pip show numpy
```

etc....

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer best. `pip freeze` shows a ton of extra crap if you've pip'd in a bunch of packages.

Answer (score 7):

Run `pip list` in a *Linux terminal* and find Django and its version in the list:

Run `pip freeze` on cmd on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Django will use the version of Python specified by the PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can use `echo $PYTHONPATH` in a shell to determine which version will be used.

The module versions used by Django will be the module versions installed under the version of Python specified by PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 5):

There is an undocumented `utils` versions module in Django:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/version.py

With that, you can get the normal version as a string or a detailed version tuple:

```
>>> from django.utils import version
>>> version.get_version()
... 1.9
>>> version.get_complete_version()
... (1, 9, 0, 'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without Python too. Just type this in your Django directory:

```
cat __init__.py | grep VERSION
```

And you will get something like:

```
VERSION = (1, 5, 5, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: This is great when you don't want to activate the virtual env just to get a value, or you're using something like AWS Elastic Beanstalk and can't activate the virtual env.

Comment: @rjferguson you dont need to activate your env to do a `pip freeze` / `python -c "import <module>; <module>.VERSION"`. You can simply reference it: `/path/to/env/bin/python -c "<command>"` or if you want to install/use pip, same thing: `/path/to/env/bin/pip freeze`. I use this all the time, specially when im logged in as a root and all of my application code runs as `www-data` i do: `sudo su www-data -c "/path/to/env/bin/pip install <module>"` and not even blink. (i know this is almost 2 years later, and you probably know about it now -- this is more for the next guy)

Comment: > without Python
>> python -c

Answer (score 4):

The most pythonic way I've seen to get the version of *any* package:

```
>>> import pkg_resources;
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('django').version
'1.8.4'
```

This ties directly into setup.py: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.py#L37

Also there is `distutils` to compare the version:

```
>>> from distutils.version import LooseVersion, StrictVersion
>>> LooseVersion("2.3.1") < LooseVersion("10.1.2")
True
>>> StrictVersion("2.3.1") < StrictVersion("10.1.2")
True
>>> StrictVersion("2.3.1") > StrictVersion("10.1.2")
False
```

As for getting the `python` version, I agree [with James Bradbury](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468397/how-to-check-django-version/26386738#26386738):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.3 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:18:23) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]'
```

Tying it all together:

```
>>> StrictVersion((sys.version.split(' ')[0])) > StrictVersion('2.6')
True
```

Answer (score 4):

After django 1.0 you can just do this

```
$ django-admin --version
1.11.10
```

Answer (score 3):

**Type the following command in Python shell**

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

Answer (score 3):

Python version supported by Django version

```
Django version        Python versions
----------------------------------------
1.0                   2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6
1.1                   2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6
1.2                   2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7
1.3                   2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7
1.4                   2.5, 2.6, 2.7
1.5                   2.6.5, 2.7 and 3.2.3, 3.3 (experimental)
1.6                   2.6.5, 2.7 and 3.2.3, 3.3
1.11                  2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 (added in 1.11.17)
2.0                   3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7
2.1, 2.2              3.5, 3.6, 3.7
```

To verify that Django can be seen by Python, type `python` from your shell. Then at the Python prompt, try to import Django:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
2.1
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 1, 4, 'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make Django version comparison, you could use `django-nine` (pip install django-nine). For example, if Django version installed in your environment is 1.7.4, then the following would be true.

```
from nine import versions

versions.DJANGO_1_7 # True
versions.DJANGO_LTE_1_7 # True
versions.DJANGO_GTE_1_7 # True
versions.DJANGO_GTE_1_8 # False
versions.DJANGO_GTE_1_4 # True
versions.DJANGO_LTE_1_6 # False
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get django version by running the following command in a shell prompt

**python -m django --version**

If Django is installed, you should see the version otherwise you’ll get an error telling “No module named django”.

Answer (score 1):

you can import django and then type print statement as given below to know the version of django i.e. installed on your system:

```
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
2.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your CMD or Terminal and run any of the following commands

```
django-admin --version
        or
python3 -m django --version
        or
pip freeze
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you can get the version of Django by using any of the two below.

```
import django
print(django.__version__)
# '3.1.5'
print(django.VERSION)
# (3, 1, 5, 'final', 0)
```

or from your terminal, you can run

```
django-admin --version
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]It's very simple open the CLI(command line or any IDE) wherever you installed python and Django just type,

django-admin --version

see here I have installed the latest Python and Django in my system and the result is shown in fig.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more methods to get the Version (of Django and other packages).
Both of them need a **version** variable for the package to get the version.
According to [PEP-396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/#id27) the __version__variable should be set for every Python module.

---

**Method 1 - Get version from filesystem**

With that in mind, you know how to get the version for almost every Django/Python package. Look inside the __init__.py of the package root.
So if you are a fast at navigating through the filesystem, this can be a very universal way of getting the Version of any package inside your site-package (virtual environment).

---

**Method 2 - Django Debug Toolbar**

There is a very helpful tool that is called [django debug toolbar](https://pypi.org/project/django-debug-toolbar/).
If you use it (very recommendable for Django development) you can list the versions of all apps that have a package.__version__.

[image: django-debug-toolbar-versions]

Answer (score 0):

These commands below get **Django version**:

```
django-admin --version
```

```
python manage.py --version
```

But, these commands below get **error**:

```
django-admin -v
```

```
python manage.py -v
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the Django version installed on your Windows PC,

**In a Terminal session, run**:

```
py -m Django --version
```

**Or in a Python REPL**:

```
import Django
django.get_version()
```

**To check the Django version installed in your active virtual environment (venv), run**:

```
Django-admin --version
```

**Note that the Django version installed on your PC might be different from the version installed in your active virtual environment**.

Answer (score -1):

go the setting of the Django Project. there find your Django Version.