# Finding django version number for an old project

Tags: python, django, version

I'm starting on a project that someone began >2 years ago and I'm having trouble figuring out what version of django it runs. The person who made the project doesn't know, and I'm not sure guessing and checking would work, since I don't actually know that the project compiles. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530231/get-the-version-of-django-for-application) answer, but it suggests that the version is pre-1.0, and I'm not really sure where to go from there. Is there a good way of telling what the version is, besides guessing and checking?

My settings.py is

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'site.db') # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# Absolute path to the directory that holds media.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# URL prefix for admin media -- CSS, JavaScript and images. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/media/", "/media/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = some gibberish

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

#ROOT_URLCONF = 'site.urls'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'project.site',
)

#TD_SERVER_PORT = 'tcp:8080:interface=192.168.1.43'
#TD_BIN_DIR = '/Users/me/django/project/bin'
TD_WORK_DIR = '/Users/me/td_work'
TD_COMPACT_MODE = False
TD_MAX_UPLOAD_RATE = 20 * 1024
TD_MAX_DOWNLOAD_RATE = 80 * 1024
#TD_LISTEN_PORT_MIN = 59543
#TD_LISTEN_PORT_MAX = 59553
TD_LISTEN_PORT_MIN = 6881
TD_LISTEN_PORT_MAX = 6891

# Icecast stream upload settings.
TD_STREAM_NAME = '[o_o] site.net'
TD_STREAM_PORT = 8000
#TD_STREAM_HOST = 'thingie.com'
#TD_STREAM_PASSWORD = 'poiuyt'
TD_STREAM_HOST = 'localhost'
TD_STREAM_PASSWORD = 'qwerty'
#TD_STREAM_HOST = 'otherthingie.com'
#TD_STREAM_PASSWORD = 'wopwopwop'

# CD Ripper
TD_CD_DIR = '/home/me/td_work/cds'
```

My manage.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from project.site.models import Syndicator, Torrent

torrent = {
    'queryset': Torrent.objects.all(),
    'extra_context': {'syndicators': Syndicator.objects.all()},
}

torrents = {
    'queryset': Torrent.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date'),
    'paginate_by': 25,
    'allow_empty': True,
    'extra_context': {'syndicators': Syndicator.objects.all()},
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', torrents, 'home-page'),

    (r'^feeds/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', torrents, 'feed-list'),
    (r'^feeds/page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', torrents, 'feed-list-page'),
    (r'^feeds/post/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail', torrent, 'feed-post'),
    (and a lot more patterns),
)
```

Comment: This needs more info. Show your `settings.py`, `manage.py` and `urls.py`.

Comment: Take a look at models. Do models define `Admin` class inside?

Comment: Convention like `DATABASE_NAME` was dropped in Django 1.4, so let's focus od 1.3 and below. Is there a `admin.py` file? What is defined `admin.site.urls` pattern in the `urls.py` file?

Comment: @pancakes yup, <=1.3 - this is what my answer is about. Check it out.

Comment: There's no admin.py, and the string 'admin' appears nowhere in the urls.py file

Answer (score 3):

```
(virtualenv)~$ python

>>> import django
>>> print django.get_version()
'1.4.1'
```

Comment: This tells me what version my machine runs, not what version the project is.

Comment: Hmm, there is no simple answer. I suggest you to look at the (both django and project) configuration files - there was many changes during django development. Show as example urls, database declaration etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it matters exactly. The database settings imply pre-1.2, so 1.1 should work fine. Django very rarely breaks backwards compatibility (that database one is a rare exception) so differences between point versions shouldn't have much impact.