# How can I show the django version in pycharm？

Tags: python, django

I want to see the django version in my Pycharm terminal, but I don't get the correct method.

I tried bellow methods in pycharm terminal:

1) `django --version` and `django version`
2) import django, and print the version by:

```
import django
print django.VERSION
```

But I still can not get it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Django version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468397/how-to-check-django-version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot print the Django version from the python console in Pycharm, go to settings>Project:project_name>project Interpreter and from the list of installed packages see the installed Django and it's version for that project.

Answer (score 1):

You can run pip freeze too.  Just filtering the results with grep...

```
pip freeze | grep Django
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal you can use bellow command to check the version of django:

```
python -m django --version
```

If you want to use your second method, just like this bellow command:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.VERSION)"
(1, 11, 2, u'final', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a version attribute, but you can find out Django's version using the `get_version` method:

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

Answer (score 0):

go to setting > project > project Interpreter and install **Django** package 
then **run** the code

import django

print(django.get_version())

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
A .txt file with that name will be created automatically, open the file and check for the django version and other previously installed libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about pychram but the most efficient way to query the django version without importing django globally would be this:

```
from django import VERSION as DJANGO_VERSION

if DJANGO_VERSION >= (2, 0):
    pass
```

What was not proposed in this question which is something similar:
[How to check Django version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468397/how-to-check-django-version)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. The solution is simple. 
Just create a project, open settings.py file and observe the first comment lines. You will see the version info in there as displayed below:

[Image of settings.py that shows the Django version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0XzN.png)

I found the solution [here](http://big.info/2016/07/check-django-version-pycharm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command on terminal will give you django version

```
 python -m django --version
```

Or
You can go to the interactive python prompt and use the command

```
import django
print(django.get_version())
```

or using pip freeze and grep you can also get the django version

```
pip freeze | grep Django
```